# Gmail desktop notifications: no sound

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, gmail, franz

I started using [desktop notifications from Gmail](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Gmail-Desktop-Notifications) and although they work generally ok, I get no sound.

I tried this on Franz 4.0.4, on Wmail 1.3.1, on Firefox 49 and on Chrome 53, using Ubuntu 16.04.1. I know that I can use a notifier plugin on Firefox but what I want is to make the desktop notifications work (so that I can use Franz). Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that Franz is still in Beta. Do you suppose this might be better as a feature request for the Franz developers?

Comment: I have submitted a ticket to Franz but I strongly believe there is another problem in my system that prevents the audio from working.

Comment: is your audio working with other applications?

Comment: Yes, it works with other applications and I get sound in the notifications e.g. from Telegram.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to indicate why my answer failed to solve your problem?

Comment: @ElderGeek Since the original form of the question I have written that I am not looking for an extra plugin (which restricts me on a browser and workflow) but to make the actual desktop notifications feature of Gmail work properly. I edited my answer to include a link from this feature. Your answer suggests that I install an extension for Chrome (i.e. keep Chrome installed) to bypass/hide the problem, so it doesn't answer my question. There can actually be more instances of the same problem on my system that I haven't seen yet because of a wrong setting or so. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Actually, you mentioned a plugin for firefox.  Editing answer.

Comment: Again, I suggest that you review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask specifically the final paragraph about keeping an open mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything anywhere that stated that Gmail Desktop Notifications provided audio notification. (Although it appears some expect it.)

One possibility to obtain the results you want would be to use an extension called Checker Plus for Google Chrome allows you to receive **desktop and audio** notifications for Gmail. **This functions even when the Gmail window is closed**, making it a handy tool for keeping track of new messages outside of the Gmail app (In Franz for instance?) it can be downloaded free from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) so you can try it out without much risk. Once installed, you need to log in to your Gmail account to activate it. More information is available at the source listed below.

Note that for this to work **a supported browser is required**. Here is an excerpt from the [Gmail Desktop Notifications help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1075549?hl=en)

You can get email notifications on **Google Chrome, Firefox, or Safari** **when you're signed in to Gmail and have it open in your browser**.

Note: You won't **see** any notifications if you turned off all notifications for your browser.

Open Gmail.
In the top right, click Settings Settings.
Click Settings.
Scroll down to the "Desktop notifications" section.
Select New mail notifications on, Important mail notifications on, or Mail notifications off.
At the bottom of the page, click **Save Changes**.
Note: If you use inbox categories and turned on notifications for new mail, you'll only get notifications about messages in your Primary category. If you turned on notifications for important mail, you'll get notifications for everything marked as important.

Sources:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/get-notifications-for-gmail-in-chrome/

Comment: I couldn't find a mention of it doing so. Did you?

Comment: I also couldn't find any explicit mention to it, although I found some questions on why they don't hear any sound or how to change it (probably they were just talking about a plugin). This, combined with the fact that Franz provides a "mute" button for Gmail and with my experience from other websites made me think that there was just a problem. I am sorry for the confusion. Please edit your answer to state that probably Gmail doesn't provide sound with its notifications and I will accept it.